# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' , Error in meteor Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, meteor, web

I am new to angular. I am following Course for angular2. I am trying to make a web application with angular and meteor js.

My browser reporting the error **Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'**

I have a mongo collection defined:

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
export let Bookmarks = new Mongo.Collection('bookmarks');
```

And I am fetching records from the collection in my component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './bookmarklist.html';
import {Bookmarks} from '../../../../collections/bookmarks';
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';


@Component({
  selector: 'bookmark-list',
  template: template
})
export class BookmarkList {
bookmarks : Mongo.Cursor<Object>;

constructor(){
    this.bookmarks = Bookmarks.find();
    console.log(this.bookmarks);
   }
}
```

Not sure where is the problem.
I can retrieve record from the meteor mongo console...

[Meteor Mongo Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fXR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you first initiate the collection into a "const" and then export it as default:

```
const Bookmarks = new Mongo.Collections('bookmarks');
export default Bookmarks;
```

Exports can be "default" or if you export multiple constants you could export with brackets - add as {one, two, three}.

In your second snippet, I would first import meteor stuff, then everything else and the console log should be done on a find().fetch() cause find() returns a cursor not data.

```
console.log(Bookmarks.find().fetch());
```

Rgs,
Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer.. i tried to export Bookmarks as you said but i am getting error **'Module collections/bookmarks has no exported member "Bookmarks" '** and in my console i am getting **"Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"**

And if i export the Bookmarks as i was doing all along console.log(Bookmarks.find().fetch()) returning an empty array and i am getting error **Type {}[] is not assignable to type course<Object>, property count is missing**

Comment: In your code editor you should be having a server console. That is the server side console. In the Chrome inspector you have the client console.

Comment: I am getting module not found error in my code editor.... Cannot read property 'find' of undefined in my chrome console and type{}[] is not assignable to type cursor<Object> in my server console

Comment: If you exported as default, I hope you didn't use {} on the import side. It really looks like you don't "see" Bookmarks on both server and client which makes me think it is not declared in a common location. The issue is not related to Angular it is purely Meteor: [https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html)

Comment: Yup i did use {}... I have it out client and server folder... And u learned whatever i put outside client and server folder it runs on both .. i will try without {}

Comment: And i understand its meteor some how my server and client is not picking the collection i made

Comment: Ok now all the errors are gone but i am still getting an empty array while i am getting the records on meteor mongo ..

Comment: I am accepting your answer because i got me rid of all errors and i got my way around.. it looks like my application is not syncing up meteor console.. adding records directly from application to collections solves it ... Thanks for the response!

Comment: Hi,

I'm glad to hear you're ok now. For DB you can use Robomongo or Studio 3T and you have a Meteor plugin for Chrome. It happens sometimes that you spell the collection name wrong when adding via the console and you end up with two collections. that's why I believe you don't see records added in the console. With a Mongo client like mentioned above you can see the entire structure of DB.